# Powershell copy folder and content to destination

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I am trying to write a Powershell script that transfers my SID-1 folder to the C:\temp and then install the .exe files for each program. At the moment my efforts merely make C:\temp\SID-1\ but no subfolder or content transfers. Very new to Powershell so feel I am missing something obvious. I run these as a preloaded script in the Atera MSP.

I believe the issue is with the #Transporter section, as it is not copying the whole folder and its content. I have recently attempted to add the IF statement to create C:\temp

```
    #   Transporter
$Source = '\\server\Deployment\Standard Installs\SID-1\'
$Destination = 'C:\temp\'
Get-ChildItem $Destination | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $_ -Recurse -Force}
If(!(test-path $Destination))
{
New-Item -Path $Destination -ItemType directory
}
```

Everything else below this point is merely an installer for the programs I consider standard installs.

Below is the full script

```
    #   Transporter
$Source = '\\server\Deployment\Standard Installs\SID-1\'
$Destination = 'C:\temp\'
Get-ChildItem $Destination | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $_ -Recurse -Force}
If(!(test-path $Destination))
{
New-Item -Path $Destination -ItemType directory
}
$CurrentLocation = 'C:\temp\'
#  Installer
#EXE Preloader
$exe = @(
#   Internet Browsers
'C:\temp\SID-1\Internet Browser\ChromeSetup.exe',
'C:\temp\SID-1\Internet Browser\Firefox Installer.exe',
'C:\temp\SID-1\Internet Browser\OperaSetup.exe',
#   Office 365
'c:\temp\SID-1\Office 365\Setup.X64.en-us_O365BusinessRetail.exe',
'c:\temp\SID-1\Office 365\setuponenotefreeretail.x64.en-us_.exe',
'c:\temp\SID-1\Office 365\Teams_windows.exe',
'c:\temp\SID-1\Office 365\Yammer-ia32-3.4.5.exe',
#   Printers
'c:\temp\SID-1\Papercut\client-local-install.exe',
#   Utilities
'c:\temp\SID-1\Utilities\7z1805-x64.exe',
'c:\temp\SID-1\Utilities\GrammarlySetup.exe',
'c:\temp\SID-1\Utilities\pwsafe64-3.51.0.exe',
'c:\temp\SID-1\Utilities\readerdc_uk_xa_cra_install.exe',
'c:\temp\SID-1\Utilities\TeamViewer_Host_Setup.exe',
'c:\temp\SID-1\Utilities\AnyDesk.exe'
)
#MSI Preloader
$msi = @(
#   AntiVirus
'c:\temp\SID-1\Eset\eset_endpoint_av64.msi'
)
# foreach ($exefile in $exe)

#   Internet Browsers
#Google Chrome
Start-Process -FilePath "c:\temp\SID-1\Internet Browser\ChromeSetup.exe" -ArgumentList "/qn" -Wait
#Opera
Start-Process -FilePath "c:\temp\SID-1\Internet Browser\Firefox Installer.exe" -ArgumentList "/qn" -Wait
#Mozilla Firefox
Start-Process -FilePath "c:\temp\SID-1\Internet Browser\OperaSetup.exe" -ArgumentList "/qn" -Wait

#   Office 365
#Office 2016 Business Premium 64
Start-Process -FilePath "c:\temp\SID-1\Office 365\Setup.X64.en-us_O365BusinessRetail.exe" -ArgumentList "/qn" -Wait
#Onenote 2016
Start-Process -FilePath "c:\temp\SID-1\Office 365\setuponenotefreeretail.x64.en-us_.exe" -ArgumentList "/qn" -Wait
#Teams 64
Start-Process -FilePath "c:\temp\SID-1\Office 365\Teams_windows.exe" -ArgumentList "/qn" -Wait
#Yammer 64
Start-Process -FilePath "c:\temp\SID-1\Office 365\Yammer-ia32-3.4.5.exe" -ArgumentList "/qn" -Wait

#   AntiVirus
#ESET
Start-Process -FilePath "c:\temp\SID-1\Eset\eset_endpoint_av64.msi" -ArgumentList "/qn" -Wait

#   Printers
#Papercut
Start-Process -FilePath "c:\temp\SID-1\Papercut\client-local-install.exe" -ArgumentList "/qn" -Wait


#   Utilities
#PassVault
Start-Process -FilePath "c:\temp\SID-1\Utilities\pwsafe64-3.51.0.exe" -ArgumentList "/qn" -Wait
#Grammarly
Start-Process -FilePath "c:\temp\SID-1\Utilities\GrammarlySetup.exe" -ArgumentList "/qn" -Wait
#7zip
Start-Process -FilePath "c:\temp\SID-1\Utilities\7z1805-x64.exe" -ArgumentList "/qn" -Wait
#Adobe DC Reader
Start-Process -FilePath "c:\temp\SID-1\Utilities\readerdc_uk_xa_cra_install.exe" -ArgumentList "/qn" -Wait
#TeamViewer
Start-Process -FilePath "c:\temp\SID-1\Utilities\TeamViewer_Host_Setup.exe" -ArgumentList "/qn" -Wait
#Anydesk
Start-Process -FilePath "c:\temp\SID-1\Utilities\AnyDesk.exe" -ArgumentList "/qn" -Wait
```

Comment: So my transporter script works for placing intranet on desktops, not sure what i got wrong on this attempt.

`# Transporter
$Source = '\\server\Deployment\Standard Installs\Intranet.url'
$Destination = 'C:\Users\*\Desktop\'
Get-ChildItem $Destination | ForEach-Object {Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $_ -Recurse -Force}`

Answer (score 0):

You are copying from the destination! But there probably won't be any files.
You want to do it the other way around. Also you need to copy after the directory was created:

```
#   Transporter
$Source = '\\server\Deployment\Standard Installs\SID-1\'
$Destination = 'C:\temp\'
If(!(test-path $Destination))
{
New-Item -Path $Destination -ItemType directory
}
Get-ChildItem $source| ForEach-Object {Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $destination -Recurse -Force}
```

**Edit:**
The even better option is to copy the whole directory. You don't even have to check if the folder already exists, because the script automaticly creates the C:\temp folder if it isn't there:

```
$Source = '\\server\Deployment\Standard Installs\SID-1\'
$Destination = 'C:\temp\'    
Copy-Item -Path $source -Destination $destination -Recurse -Force
```

Please test it, let me know if it worked and if it did, mark my post as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if filepath is exist recomend do at start, like this, for me this work good.

```
$Source = '\\server\Deployment\Standard Installs\SID-1\'
$Destination = 'C:\temp\'
If(!(test-path $Destination))
{
New-Item -Path $Destination -ItemType directory
}
Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $Destination -Recurse -Force
```